# Spring MVC Can't configure Dispatcher Servlet right

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm having trouble configuring the Dispatcher for Spring. What I am trying to achieve is:

- Build REST WebService to receive requests
- Have HTML + Ajax pages consuming the data (Therefore, I don't have Views in my Spring project)

So far I have only 2 HTML pages: Login (using j_security_check) and Main page. Both very simple. I also have a simple controller:

MainController.java

```
@RestController //Or @Controller and @ResponseBody, no difference, right?
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping("rest/main/data")
    public String getData () {
        return "{data: \"DATA HUEHUE\"}"; // Yes, I'm brazilian
    }

}
```

And I have tried the following configuration for web.xml and dispatcher-servlet.xml:

web.xml:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.controller"/>
```

This doesn't work. I get the message `INFO: Mapped URL path [/rest/main/data] onto handler 'mainController'` but when I try to access I get `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/rest/main/data] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'`

I also have tried:

- On web.xml: `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`
- On dispatcher-servlet: The same
- What happened: The controller DID work but the application also tried to map my login.html and couldnt find a match so I got 404 ;-;

I'm aware of that "standard" configuration using a prefix and a sufix, but since I dont have views here I dont think that's the right approach.
I'm kinda new at Spring (as you may have noticed), so please be gentle on the answers.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance :)

My project tree:

```
-project
--src
---main
----webapp
-----WEB-INF
------web.xml
------weblogic.xml
------dispatcher-servlet.xml
-----www
------main.html
-----login.html
```

(Login is outside www)

Comment: Where is your handlerMapping in `dispatcher-servlet.xml`. So please provide your complete  `dispatcher-servlet.xml` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

With the first approach if you modify the controller code to have `/rest/main/data` It will work.

```
@RestController //Or @Controller and @ResponseBody, no difference, right?
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping("/rest/main/data")
    public String getData () {
        return "{data: \"DATA HUEHUE\"}"; // Yes, I'm brazilian
    }

}
```

What is happening in happening in the second approach is that since you have Spring Security configured you need to be authenticated first but for that it finds the Login.html and can not find it. This may be because of incorrect configuration.

Comment: Hi Shazin, thanks. I tried what you said, put a `/` before `rest` but still didnt work. I got the same messages. That the URL Path was mapped but when I tried to access it said no mapping found for the URL. :/ I even cleaned the project.
About the second approch, I don't it is the case of what you said. Actually I rechecked and I can access my login.html page. When I try to access my main page tough I get `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/trackmydata/www/main.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'`. **I updated my post above with my project tree**